# Web.config regex OR oporator

Tags: regex, web-config

I have the following rule in my webconfig

```
<rule name="accommidationRewrite2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="accommodation/(?!results|!property).*?(.*)/" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm/?path=/accommodation/results/params/location/{R:1}/" />
            </rule>
```

I'm trying to get the rule to kick in is the URL is not 'accommodation/results/....' OR 'accommodation/property/.....'

At the moment it only work for the results URL. Can I get it to work for both URL's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `!` symbol which was present before the `property` ,

```
accommodation/(?!results|property).*?(.*)/
```

Comment: Well that was simple. Cheers